# Gremlin shortest path

Tags: gremlin

1- What is the difference between using the the shortestPathVertexProgram and running something like "g.V(1).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasId(5)).path().limit(1)" using the TraversalVertexProgram.

This comes down to the more general question: is it worth implementing a parallelized algorithm (if possible at all) and implementing it in a Pregel like fashion using low primitive of message passing as can be seen in the code of the shortestPath [vertexProgram](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/6a705098b5176086c667b94fa9e13aa2f122bb59/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/computer/search/path/ShortestPathVertexProgram.java), or it is better to simply write it as a traversal and execute it as a parallel traversal? What's the complexity difference between the two approach ?

My intuition is that the former would be faster, but it seems like the VertexProgram API is hard, not super documented, and there is no super tutorial about it such as in GraphX Pregel API.